# HOW to MERGE in neo4j using JAVA

Tags: neo4j

Hi I am trying to insert two properties of a node....I am trying like below..
I am trying to add two properties to CUSTOMER NODE
1.name and 2.TOTAL_CALL_DURATION
How can I add two properties

```
    try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
            {
                String queryString = "MERGE (n:CUSTOMER {name:{name},TOTAL_CALL_DURATION:{TOTAL_CALL_DURATION}}) RETURN n";
                Map<String, Object> callerProperties = new HashMap<>();
                callerProperties.put( "name", callerName );
                callerProperties.put("TOTAL_CALL_DURATION", 120);
              resultIterator_caller = execEngine.execute( queryString, callerProperties ).columnAs( "n" );
              tx.success();
}
```

The error I am getting like below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.cypher.ParameterNotFoundException: Expected a parameter named TOTAL_CALL_DURATION
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.QueryState$$anonfun$getParam$1.apply(QueryState.scala:45)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.QueryState$$anonfun$getParam$1.apply(QueryState.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.QueryState.getParam(QueryState.scala:45)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.commands.expressions.ParameterExpression.apply(ParameterExpression.scala:27)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.helpers.PropertySupport$$anonfun$firstNullPropertyIfAny$1.isDefinedAt(PropertySupport.scala:29)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.helpers.PropertySupport$$anonfun$firstNullPropertyIfAny$1.isDefinedAt(PropertySupport.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$collectFirst$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:132)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$collectFirst$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.collectFirst(TraversableOnce.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.collectFirst(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.helpers.PropertySupport$.firstNullPropertyIfAny(PropertySupport.scala:28)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.mutation.MergeNodeAction.ensureNoNullNodeProperties(MergeNodeAction.scala:95)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.mutation.MergeNodeAction.exec(MergeNodeAction.scala:73)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_1$pipes$ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$exec(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:57)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPi$$$$1019fdff8b266d7d9d5647386930b3d8$$$$ands$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:46)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPi$$$$1019fdff8b266d7d9d5647386930b3d8$$$$ands$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:46)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ClosingIterator.scala:37)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$failIfThrows$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:93)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ClosingIterator.decoratedCypherException(ClosingIterator.scala:102)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterator.scala:91)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ClosingIterator.hasNext(ClosingIterator.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ClosingIterator.foreach(ClosingIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ClosingIterator.to(ClosingIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:257)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.ClosingIterator.toList(ClosingIterator.scala:28)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.EagerPipeExecutionResult.<init>(EagerPipeExecutionResult.scala:32)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:125)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:119)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.runWithQueryState(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:168)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:118)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:103)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:68)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:67)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionPlanWrapperForV2_1.execute(CypherCompiler.scala:159)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:76)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:71)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:84)
    at com.emc.neo4jConnectivity.NodeCreation.createNodes(NodeCreation.java:84)
    at com.emc.neo4jConnectivity.NodeCreation.main(NodeCreation.java:136)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, I've converted it into a self-contained `groovy` script running fine without any errors.

Try to provide a minimal viable testcase showing the error you're observing

For reference, here's the script:

```
@Grapes([
@Grab(group="org.neo4j", module="neo4j-kernel", version="2.1.8", classifier="tests"),
@Grab(group="org.neo4j", module="neo4j-kernel", version="2.1.8"),
@Grab(group="org.neo4j", module="neo4j-cypher", version="2.1.8")
])
import org.neo4j.test.TestGraphDatabaseFactory
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil

def graphDb = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabaseBuilder().newGraphDatabase()
def executionEngine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb)

def resultIterator_caller
def tx = graphDb.beginTx()
try {          
    String queryString = "MERGE (n:CUSTOMER {name:{name},TOTAL_CALL_DURATION:{TOTAL_CALL_DURATION}}) RETURN n";
    Map<String, Object> callerProperties = new HashMap<>();
    callerProperties.put( "name", "abc" );
    callerProperties.put("TOTAL_CALL_DURATION", 120);
    resultIterator_caller = executionEngine.execute( queryString, callerProperties ).columnAs( "n" );
    tx.success()
} finally {
    tx.close()
}

// we need another tx to consume the result (since we're returning node instances)
transaction = graphDb.beginTx()
try {
    assert resultIterator_caller.hasNext() 
    def nextNode = resultIterator_caller.next()
    assert nextNode.getProperty("name",null) == "abc"
    assert nextNode.getProperty("TOTAL_CALL_DURATION",null) == 120
    assert !resultIterator_caller.hasNext()
    tx.success()
} finally {
    tx.close()
}
```